# Array of pointers for hash table

Tags: c, pointers, hash, malloc

I'm trying to implement a simple hash table in C, where I have two structures, one for the entries, and one for the table itself:

```
typedef struct hash_table_entry {
    int key;
    int data;
    struct hash_table_entry *next;
} HT_ENTRY;

typedef struct hash_table {
    int size;
    int entry_count;
    HT_ENTRY **table;
} HT;
```

My mallocs when creating the table:

```
if ((ht_table = (HT*)malloc(sizeof(HT))) == NULL)
    return NULL;
if ((ht_table->table = (HT_ENTRY**)malloc(size * (sizeof(HT_ENTRY*)))) == NULL)
    return NULL;
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if ((ht_table->table[i] = (HT_ENTRY*)malloc(sizeof(HT_ENTRY))) == NULL)
        return NULL;
}
```

When allocating the table, my second malloc doesn't create the array of pointers in the desired size I would like him to do: [pic of debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ezz0L.png)

Why does my malloc do this and what would be the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are allocating individual entries in the hash table but there is no data associated to these entries, indeed they are uninitialized, causing undefined behavior when you try and use the hash table. You should instead just initialize the array of pointers pointed to by `ht_table->table` with `NULL` pointers:

```
ht_table->size = size;
ht_table->entry_count = 0;
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    ht_table->table[i] = NULL;
}
```

Or simply allocate the array with `calloc()`:

```
ht_table->size = size;
ht_table->entry_count = 0;
if ((ht_table->table = (HT_ENTRY**)calloc(size, sizeof(HT_ENTRY*))) == NULL)
    return NULL;
```

Also not that in C, casting the return value of `malloc` and `calloc` is not required. A safer way to allocate the array is:

```
if ((ht_table->table = calloc(size, sizeof(*ht_table->table))) == NULL)
    return NULL;
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks for this, I completely forgot about initializing with nulls. I tried calloc for my problem as well, but it still makes an array of 1, no matter what size I write in.

Comment: @mynael: the array is allocated by `calloc()` to the size you specify, but the debugger onlly shows the first entry because `ht_table->table` is just a pointer to a pointer, The debugger cannot guess the number of pointers in the array it points to. Declaring it as `HT_ENTRY *table[];` might make a difference or not. Both declarations are equivalent, but this one indicates to the programmer that `table` is meant to point to an array, not to a single pointer.

Comment: Well, that clarifies a lot of things, thank you. Just when using malloc + for cycle, the  cycle gives a buffer overrun warning and I thought it's related to that. I'll just stay at calloc then.